# Azure RsaKey persistent

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm using cryptography for my Azure project and I have issues with RsaKey. When the user signs up to the application, an RsaKey is created and associated to the user. This is the code:

```
   string storageConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
                    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
                    try
                    {
                        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
                    }
                    catch (FormatException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid storage account information provided. Please confirm the AccountName and AccountKey are valid in the app.config file - then restart the sample.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        throw;
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid storage account information provided. Please confirm the AccountName and AccountKey are valid in the app.config file - then restart the sample.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        throw;
                    }
                    CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
                    CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference(tableName);
                    RsaKey key = new RsaKey(item.PartitionKey);
                    TableRequestOptions insertOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
                    {
                        EncryptionPolicy = new TableEncryptionPolicy(key, null)
                    };
                    table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(item), insertOptions, null);
```

After this I have to make RsaKey persistent, then I store it in a dedicated blob in the user container. Since RsaKey is not Serializable, I use a little "trick" with Json string. Here the code:

```
 string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(key);

                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonString), false))
                    {             
                        blob.UploadFileToBlob(item.PartitionKey, "key", stream); // this method creates a blob called "key" in the container named [item.PartitionKey] and stores the stream   
                    }
```

After registration, of course I need to use the RsaKey to perform some operations, like having access to some hide fields, having access to some special files in other blobs, etc. What I do in this case is shown in this code:

```
 User user = GetUser();

            Resolver res = new Resolver();
            res.Add(user.PartitionKey);

            TableRequestOptions retrieveOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
            {
                EncryptionPolicy = new TableEncryptionPolicy(null, res)
            };

            // Retrieve Entity
            string storageConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
            try
            {
                storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid storage account information provided. Please confirm the AccountName and AccountKey are valid in the app.config file - then restart the sample.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid storage account information provided. Please confirm the AccountName and AccountKey are valid in the app.config file - then restart the sample.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }
            CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference("user");
            TableOperation operation = TableOperation.Retrieve(user.PartitionKey, user.RowKey);
            TableResult result;
            try
            {
                 result = table.Execute(operation, retrieveOptions, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
```

Resolver is a class that implements IKeyResolver, and it must define the `ResolveKeyAsync` method to perform retrieve operations. Here is the code for this class:

```
public class Resolver: IKeyResolver
    {
        TableUtility table;
        BlobUtility blob;
        string container;

        public Resolver()
        {
            table = new TableUtility();
            blob = new BlobUtility();
        }

        public void Add(string container){
            this.container= container;
        }


        public async Task<IKey> ResolveKeyAsync(string kid, CancellationToken token)
        {
            IKey result;
            string jsonString = blob.BlobToText(container, "key"); // this method goes to the blob "key" in the container named [container] and download the content of the blob using a MemoryStream
            var javaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RsaKey>(jsonString);
            return await Task.FromResult(result);
        }

    }
```

Actually my problem is that the deserialized RsaKey is not the same of the previous one. Despite `jsonString` has the properties set correctly, The "Kid" field of `result` is different, probably cause of implicit instantiation in deserialization operation (and probably a new Kid is created). Thus, I tried to create a new RsaKey with the same Kid I stored (`RsaKey key = new RsaKey(partitionKey)`), but the retrieve operation fails (`TableResult result` remains `null`). What do you suggest? Maybe I have to change the persistence mechanism?

**EDIT**

When I try to execute `table.Execute(operation, retrieveOptions, null);`in try/catch block (with a RsaKey instantiated with `RsaKey key = new RsaKey(partitionKey)`) this is the exception thrown:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException was caught
  _HResult=-2146233088
  _message=Decryption logic threw error. Please check the inner exception for more details.
  HResult=-2146233088
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Decryption logic threw error. Please check the inner exception for more details.
  Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
  IsRetryable=false
  StackTrace:
       in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 820
       in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.Execute(CloudTableClient client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Table\TableOperation.cs:line 41
       in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.Execute(TableOperation operation, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Table\CloudTable.cs:line 53
       in WebRole.Controllers.AccountController.IsProfileCompleted() in c:\Users\HP\Source\Repos\scalablepredictor\WebRole\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 343
  InnerException: System.AggregateException
       _HResult=-2146233088
       _message=One or more errors occured.
       HResult=-2146233088
       IsTransient=false
       Message=One or more errors occured.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            in System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
            in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEncryptionPolicy.DecryptMetadataAndReturnCEK(String partitionKey, String rowKey, EntityProperty encryptionKeyProperty, EntityProperty propertyDetailsProperty, EncryptionData& encryptionData) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Table\TableEncryptionPolicy.cs:line 205
       InnerException: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
            _HResult=-2146233296
            _message=Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.
            HResult=-2146233296
            IsTransient=false
            Message=Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.
            Source=mscorlib
            StackTrace:
                 in System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)
                 in System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
                 in Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Cryptography.Algorithms.RsaOaep.RsaOaepDecryptor.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
                 in Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.RsaKey.<UnwrapKeyAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
            InnerException:
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have the same problem and it is caused by using a new instance of RSAKey. The same instance has to be used for both encryption and decryption. How do you do that in a web app?